# How to get all fields of a rows and sqrt of a field whose sqrt in MIN

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need to get all fields of a row who has min sqrt value for one column

```
SELECT name,dist, min(3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN((and many more)))) from blah
```

The min function works perfectly But the name and dist would always return from first row.

Eg. Min was from 5th row even then name and dist would be of first row

Comment: because you are using an aggregate function `min`, `group by` the other columns name,dist.

Comment: group by is not possible as it not dependent on any column but on this function min(3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN((and many more)))

Answer (score 0):

mysql version

```
 SELECT *, min(sqrt(salary)) FROM `blah`
```

Comment: nope that didn't work... I already have tried that. I return * from 1st rown and min value of other row